# Best way to equate 2 subroutines?

Tags: perl

I have many modules each of them have a sub `insert_info` and sub `update_info` methods. From time to time, the sub `update_info` and sub `insert_info` are the same. But I don't want to use only one of these methods when that happens, because in general they are not the same. So How I make the 2 methods equal?

Is this the only way?

```
 sub insert_info {
 # code......
 }

 sub update_info { insert_info(); }
```

Comment: What is wrong with that way?

Comment: @Borodin check the comments in the answer. Also, even if it were right, it's always good to know there's more than one way to do it

Comment: *Please* don't use either of the methods that `vol7ron` suggests. They are all but deprecated in anything but time-critical library code.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the comments that you say why you don't want to use your original code.

Comment: oh... that sounds a bit dangerous, i didnt get any warning notice. i actually im using it in a different branch, not production, but there were no syntaxis errors apparently and my app did run

Comment: sorry, confusion, he didn't deny my original code, he denied sub update_info = \&insert_info;

Comment: It's *"dangerous"* because you really need to fully understand what something does when you write it, and neither you nor the people that maintain your code are likely to understand typeglobs.

Comment: Ah I see. My recommendation would be to write it exactly as you have in your question. It will use infinitesimally more time and memory, but I challenge you to measure it!

Comment: I am going to measure the difference between the glob way and my way and will put the result in a comment in less than 3 business days. I'l probably use Benchmark, some work to finish first

Comment: ##TODO benchmark glob & original

Comment: Don't to forget to add the programmer time taken to look up what you code means!

Comment: @Borodin You failed entirely to spot that the asker's version doesn't preserve arguments, which rather vitiates the gravitas of your comments below on the "responsible Perl community", a phrase which in your usage seems to equate to "people who can't be bothered to learn how to use the tools they're using, and don't think anyone else should either."

Comment: @Borodin: completely disagree with your recommendation, unless you want to say ***why*** it's bad to use, other than something to the effect of *you shouldn't use the language, without knowing the language*, which is really true for everything.  I agree with [Aaron Miller] and don't think laziness is a good argument of dissuasion.  I also think if more people did use it, it'd become more common term and wouldn't be as much of an issue.  If you feel *typeglobs* are tricky and aren't commonly found in other languages, then maybe that would be a good place to put a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the [`Sub::Alias`](https://metacpan.org/module/Sub%3a%3aAlias) module from CPAN, which has the advantages of being explicit and self-documenting as well as neat and clear in use.

Your code becomes

```
use Sub::Alias 'alias';

sub insert_info {
  ...
}

alias update_info => 'insert_info';
```

Comment: My only issue is that [Sub::Alias](http://api.metacpan.org/source/GUGOD/Sub-Alias-0.03/lib/Sub/Alias.pm) is using the very method that you suggested not to use `*foo = \&bar`.  Actually, it's ***worse*** then that - it's doing `*foo = *bar` which aliasing for all the types, which is outside the scope of what the OP was asking.  *This is problematic.*  If you have `sub people {my @people=@_;}` then doing `alias person => 'people'` will be doing  `&person => &people` and `@person => @people` - do you see how this could be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

#### Alias via [typeglob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles)

```
*update_info = \&insert_info;
```

---

#### Adding BEGIN may avoid problems

```
BEGIN { *update_info = \&insert_info; }
```

This helps ensure that it runs before other things, which may call it.

---

#### Comments on your Example

Also, your `sub update_info { insert_info(); }` is not a copy because it will always call *insert_info* with no parameters.  If you passed *update_info* any values (like `update_info('someval')`), they would not be passed on to *insert_info*.  Furthermore, they are both declared and defined subroutines - both taking memory.

If you wanted to declare it how you did and automatically pass along the arguments to the inner function, you could do `sub update_info { insert_info(@_); }`, or better is `sub update_info { &insert_info }`, since the `&` without any argument list, will automatically pass along `@_`.

Still these take more memory than using the *typeglob* assignment, listed at the top.

Comment: thats a nice one. what's the meaning of the * at the beginning? can it be replace for sub update_info = \&insert_info;?

Comment: `*` is the sigil that represents a [typeglob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles), which could represent any variable type with that name (eg `@update_info`,`$update_info`,`%update_info`,etc).  However when the rhs is typed, it will match the sigil.

Comment: you cannot do `sub update_info = \&insert_info;` however you could make a reference by doing `my $update_info = \&insert_info;`, which you would call by `$update_info->()` or `&$update_info;`

Comment: @adriancdperu: I updated the answer to give you some more information.

Comment: @vol7ron: Typeglobs are ugly and messy things, and shouldn't be recommended for production code. The OP has never come across them, and it is likely that no one who comes to maintain this code will understand it either. Nor is it a good idea to promote the `&` form of subroutine call, which the rest of the responsible Perl community is trying hard to discourage.

Comment: @Borodin perhaps my methods are dated; would you also suggest using `goto`?  Besides neophytes not knowing what they are, I've never seen typeglobs discouraged.  I also have not seen `&` discouraged, rather I've seen an effort to re-educate the difference between `&foo`, `&foo()`, and `foo()`.  In fact, usually dispatch tables are advised, which generally always uses that notation, bar anonymous subroutines.

Comment: @vol7ron: Use of typeglobs is a low-level optimisation that is best avoided in favour of clarity unless you are writing library software or other code that is time-critical. I can't see any reason to use `goto &sub` except that it *is* more explcit that the punctuation tomfoolery involved in assigning to typeglobs. Current wisdom is that you should *never* use `&` to call a subroutine: it is necessary an appropriate only when you are working with the subroutine as an object, such as to take its reference.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the rare opportunities to use `goto` without being shamed for it.

```
sub update_info {
    goto &insert_info;
}
```

This has the benefit of passing along any arguments to the inner function, and cleaning up the `caller()` stack to remove the call to the outer function.

Comment: Better to just use the typeglob alias, or other methods mentioned. goto's of this type are slow compared to regular function calls. Cleaning up the call stack is not free.

Comment: @runrig: And the chance that you will notice any difference is very remote indeed.

Comment: @Borodin: so if I can't tell the difference, I may as well go with the simplest and most efficient solution...the typeglob alias.

Comment: @runrig: I am sure you are deliberately missing the point. The meanings of star, backslash and ampersand are impssible to guess in general. And, even knowing them, *"Assign a subroutine reference to a typeglob"* means nothing without some advanced Perl knowledge. `goto &insert_info`, on the other hand, is rather simple to guess at. Typeglob manipulation should be avoided in production code if you wish to behave responsibly, in the same way that XS code and `Inline::C` have no place there.